# Show that $[(n+1)(2n+1)]^n > 6^n n!$ without using induction

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Show that for all n>1 we have that $[(n+1)(2n+1)]^n > 6^n n!$  .  n belongs to integers .

> What i considered was as $(n+1)(2n+1)$ function is increasing . So we have $(n+1)(2n+1)>6 \forall n>1 $ now from here i can show partially when i raise the power , but how do i get the factorial part ?

Comment: Do you know about induction?

Comment: Oh soory i forgot writing above ,that i was looking for proof without induction

Comment: Well, as soon as $(2n+1)≥6$ you just need to remark that $(n+1)^n>n!$ which should be clear to you.

Comment: Oh i see fine. Thanks

Comment: You could potentially use Sterling's approximation

Comment: Thanks surely will try eith that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Another approach.

We know (by [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)) that

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$$
As a consequence,
$$\big((n+1)(2n+1)\big)^n=\left(\frac{6}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\right)^n$$
Cancelling a common $6^n$ from both sides of the original problem, we are left to prove
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n}\right)^n> n!$$
Because all the terms are positive, it is very obvious that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n}> \sum_{k=n}\frac{k^2}{n}=\frac{n^2}{n}=n$$
Just by taking the last term. So,
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{n}\right)^n> n^n>n!$$
As long as $n>1$.

Answer (score 4):

I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - n & = \frac{2n^{2} + 3n + 1}{6} - n = \frac{2n^{2} - 3n + 1}{6} \geq 0
\end{align*}

for every $n\geq 1$. Consequently, one gets the desired result:
\begin{align*}
\left[\frac{(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}\right]^{n} \geq n^{n} \geq n!
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!